# Change user's pwdChangedTime attribute in openldap

Tags: openldap

When I change pwdChangedTime in Openldap, it gives an error like the following. How can I change the pwdChangetime value as admin without changing the user's password?

> ldap_modify: Constraint violation (19)
>           additional info: pwdChangedTime: no user modification allowed

How can I change user's pwdChangedTime attribute in openldap 2.4.41?

Answer (score 1):

As you already experienced *pwdChangedTime* is a special attribute set by the server, a so-called *operational* attribute. Normally this cannot be altered by a user application.

But OpenLDAP supports the so-called [Relax Rules control](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-zeilenga-ldap-relax) which can be used if the bound client is authorized for manage operations.

When using OpenLDAP CLI tools you can simply use:

```
ldapmodify -e relax [..more options..]
```